# Changing Font Size in SAS - PROC BOXPLOT

Tags: sas, boxplot, proc

I am using PROC BOXPLOT in SAS, and it is giving me output in .png. I want to change the font size for the output tables so it is readable but I am not sure how to do it with the code I have.

```
axis1 order = (40 to 120 by 10)
label = (height = 1.25 'Score')
minor = (number = 1) ;
axis2 order = (-.5 0 .5 1.5 3)
label = (height = 1.25 'Time') ;

proc boxplot data = finaldata ;
plot Score * TIMENEW1 / vaxis = axis1   
haxis = axis2
cboxfill = ORANGE CONTINUOUS
boxstyle=schematic
cboxes = BL ; 
insetgroup N MEAN Q1 Q2 Q3 MIN MAX STDDEV/ header = 'Stats by TIME'
pos = top
cfill = YELLOW ;
run;
```

Output looks like this (had to censor data points, sorry):
[image: Boxplot output]

Basically I need to make those N/Mean/Q1..etc. fonts larger.

Comment: Why don't you look a the documentation for the INSETGROUP statement.  You might find and option like HEIGHT=.

Comment: HEIGHT=value specifies height of inset and header text, not the actual text itself unfortunately.

Comment: Sounds like an answer to me, @data_null_ .  I can't verify - when I convert this to use SASHELP.CARS it doesn't seem to respect my INSET options, and I don't know base SAS/GRAPH well enough to know why.

Comment: @vanellope1 You'd be better off reposting the example with the SASHELP.CARS dataset (or another one, if more appropriate, like SASHELP.CLASS or SASHELP.HEART or similar) so we can run the code easily.

Comment: I don't know how, but I somehow did it. @$@#%#%!@$

Comment: Then please figure out how, and post it :)  Preferably with a SASHELP dataset as data source so it's more useful to others.